# How to save variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to use compare function in HTML

```
html:

{{compare "var1" "var2"}}

js:

Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(var1, var2) {
  return var1 === var2;
});
```

Here `var1` is taken from Database: it is `{{this.DATATYPE}}`
var 2 is "Text".

I want to print text box when `var1==var2`

Doing this in meteor app.

is there any way to save DB values in html when passing it into compare()?

Comment: Does this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes ?

Comment: No the DB values are extracted in HTML only